# How to convert a model class with a list of other model classes to json in dart?

Tags: json, dictionary, dart, google-cloud-firestore, model

I am implementing a model class of a team in Dart. Every instance has a unique id (from Firestore), a String name and a list of users called members. I'm trying to write a toJson function, which would convert it to a map, so I could upload it to Firestore. Here's my class:

```
class Team extends Equatable {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final List<CustomUser> members;

  Team(this.id, this.name, this.members);

  Team.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  : id = json["id"],
    name = json["name"],
    members = json["members"];

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id, name, members];
}
```

The current state of the toJson method:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {"id": id, "name": name, "members": members};
```

My problem with this is that it converts the whole instance of the user into a map, but I only want the id of every member in my json, how could I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account that CustomUser has **id** property:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {"id": id, "name": name, "members": members.map((member) => member.id).toList()};
```